# Uninstalling iTunes in Wine

Tags: wine

I've finally managed to install this program only to try and remove iTunes because every time I try to start it up, it gives me the message to reinstall it again and *error 7*.

How do I uninstall iTunes?

Comment: um... what?  itunes doesnt have a linux client.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Once a person downloads the program wine, a person can then use itunes on ubuntu. Although, it is not working.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @Dave B.: If someone's answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 9):

Open a terminal and type `wine uninstaller`. Select iTunes from the list and click remove.

Comment: This is a lot better than straight-up deleting as this should clean up after itself a lot better.

Comment: Uninstalling iTunes in this way didn't work for me.  It disappears from the list of installed programs but the files are still there. Trying to reinstall gives and error, which I think is what the original question must have ben referring to :(

Answer (score 3):

First off, i think you need some clarification:  any files installed via Wine dont end up in Synaptic Package Manager, nor are they installed as packages in the Linux/Debian sense (as a result, i've removed those tags, and replaced it with [wine](/questions/tagged/wine))

To remove programs installed with Wine (in this case, iTunes), Configure Wine, or Wine Software tool, whichever it is, to run the uninstaller.  Or go into `~/.wine/drive_c/program files/...` (whatever the path is for iTunes), and run its own uninstaller.

Also, in future, you should [use this site](http://appdb.winehq.org/) to determine application compatibility with Wine.  This way, you dont have to deal with learning after-the-fact that your installed software wont work.

Comment: @DaveB [Here's the rundown for iTunes](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347).  Anything with a 'bronze' rating i do not recommend, 'garbage' is what it says, 'silver' is okay, but anything older than iTunes 10 is technically ancient and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue but what I did that helped was to remove the itune fold at Nautilus. Press `ALT` and `F2` simultaneously and type `gks nautilus` and look for the itune folder and delete it.