# installing iTunes

Tags: wine

Hi guys I’m newbie in Ubuntu world!
So guys I’m running Ubuntu 14.04 / 64bits, and I installed iTunes 64 bits version 10.7.0 using wine!
While trying to run iTunes I always get this error:
Itunes was not properly installed. If you wish to import or burn CDs you need to reinstall iTunes.

Then when I click Ok, I get this screen::[image]

I tried to run: sudo apt-get update in the terminal, didn't work
I also tried to restart my laptop didn't work either. I need help to make it work properly so that I can  connect my idevices. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes is [generally considered](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347) not to work well under Wine. The default version of Wine in 14.04 is 1.6.2 so you could try upgrading to the [PPA development build](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa)... But I doubt that'll fix much.

I certainly wouldn't try to use it to manage hardware. In my opinion, that is inviting an expensive disaster.

---

The only real alternative I have is running a real copy of Windows in a virtualisation solution like VirtualBox or VMWare. These can pass-through USB devices to let the virtualised software manage them.

In my experience this works pretty well but it's fairly slow.

Comment: So basically there’s no way that i could manage my idevices in Ubuntu!!!

Comment: Tell Apple you want iTunes for Linux. You wouldn't be able to do it on Windows either unless they provided the software to allow it.

Comment: yeah i will try to run virtualBox then, but since i'm running Ubuntu alongside with windows i guess will continue switch to windows to run itunes,

Comment: i can't think in a reason they dont wanna provide a itunes for Linux

Comment: so any of you guys can show me step by step how to remove it(iTunes)!!

Comment: Run `wine uninstaller` in a terminal to get to the Add/Remove dialogue. See: http://askubuntu.com/q/102685/449